# Send form data to API rest

Tags: forms, rest

I am trying make a simple form where the user can enter a phone number and then get a sms. I have tried to set it up with the API from gatewayapi.com and the documentation here: https://gatewayapi.com/docs/apis/rest/

Can someone help me setup an example with this an with an input field for phone number and a submit button?

I actually only have this from the documentation:

```
POST /rest/mtsms HTTP/1.1
Host: gatewayapi.com
Authorization: Basic R28tQ3JlYXRlLWFuLUFQSS10b2tlbjoK Accept: application/json, text/javascript
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "message": "Hello World",
    "recipients": [
        {"msisdn": 4512345678},
        {"msisdn": 4587654321}
    ]
}
```

and this as a basic form:

```
<form>
    <input type="number" id="phone" name="phone">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I don't know how to "connect" the two elements

Comment: Hi! Please share the code you wrote, so we can help better. 

Comment: I actually only have this from the documentation:

   POST /rest/mtsms HTTP/1.1
   Host: gatewayapi.com
   Authorization: Basic R28tQ3JlYXRlLWFuLUFQSS10b2tlbjoK Accept: application/json, text/javascript
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "message": "Hello World",
    "recipients": [
        {"msisdn": 4512345678},
        {"msisdn": 4587654321}
    ]
}

and this as a basic form:

  <form>
        <input type="number" id="phone" name="phone">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

I don't know how to "connect" the two elements

Comment: @Shahriar I tried to add the code to the comment, but did no succeed, so added it to the question.

Hope someone can help

Comment: I meant adding code to the question at first, but no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help:
[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

You basically need something like this:

```html
<form action="gatewayapi.com" method="POST">
    <input type="number" id="phone" name="phone">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```